# Testing mongodb database with mocha and request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, request, tdd

I've got 2 questions that I am searching for an answer for 3 days so far and can't figure it out.
1. When I should connect to the database when testing?
2. I always get an error when running the test: { "before each" hook for "should list all books on /book GET" } and haven't yet found a solution or the exact cause for it. What am I doing wrong? The only answer I have so far is not to call done() twice in beforeEach() but I ain't doing it...

```
var chai      = require('chai'),
    expect    = chai.expect,
    request   = require('request'), 
    mongoose  = require('mongoose'),
    Book      = require('./../models/book');
// book = require('../model')

mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/books');

describe('Testing the routes', () => {
    beforeEach((done) => {
        Book.remove({}, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
        var newBook = new Book();
        newBook.title  = "Lord Of The Rings";
        newBook.author = "J. R. R. Tolkien";
        newBook.pages  = 1234;
        newBook.year   = 2000;
        newBook.save((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            done();
        });
    });

    it('should list all books on /book GET', (done) => {
        var url = 'http://localhost:8080/book';
        request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
            expect(body).to.be.an('array');
            expect(body.length).to.equal(1);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mongoose.createConnection` is an asynchronous function. The function returns and Node.js continues on before the connection is actually established.

Mongoose returns promises for most asynchronous functions. Similar to using `done`, mocha supports waiting for promises to resolve/reject out of the box. As long as the promise is the `return` value to the mocha function.

```
describe('Testing the routes', function(){

    before('connect', function(){
        return mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/books')
    })

    beforeEach(function(){
        return Book.remove({})
    })

    beforeEach(function(){
        var newBook = new Book();
        newBook.title  = "Lord Of The Rings";
        newBook.author = "J. R. R. Tolkien";
        newBook.pages  = 1234;
        newBook.year   = 2000;
        return newBook.save();
    });

    it('should list all books on /book GET', function(done){
        var url = 'http://localhost:8080/book';
        request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) done(error)
            expect(body).to.be.an('array');
            expect(body.length).to.equal(1);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Also mocha makes use of `this` for configuration so avoid using arrow functions for the mocha definitions.

Comment: Oki, just understood it now. This is more than I could've asked for. So promises are one thing I have to get into more. Thanks a lot!